# Owl Carousel Transitions Effect Not Working After Chrome Owl Carousel 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, css-transitions, owl-carousel

I'm using owl carouse latest version (2.0.0) 
it is working smoothly on frefox and ie but
I'm getting error on chrome (Uncaught TypeError: elem[type] is not a function)

```
on line 2972
                    jQuery.event.triggered = type;
                    elem[ type ](); /* here */
                    jQuery.event.triggered = undefined;
```

owl.jcarudel.js (2.0) does not contain a similar line to older version
like

```
support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length === 1);
```

how can I solve this problem with this version?

Comment: what is your Jquery version.

Comment: I used jquery ver. 1.8.3

Comment: do you try with latest version :like  http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Comment: I just tried all jquer version between 2.1.4 and 1.8.3 but the result didn't change

Comment: post you demo code in jsfiddle

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?